# Что может вызвать статус 400?

Tags: asp.net-core, angular

Я делаю post запрос на сервер, но получаю ошибку в консоли: status 400:"One or more validation errors occurred."

Сервис angular:

```
 public createCart(cart:ShoppingCart):Observable<any>{
    return this.httpClient.post<ShoppingCart>(
      `${environment.apiUrl}/${this.url}/cart`,
      cart
    )
  }
```

Компонент:

```
  this.cartService.getMe().subscribe((result)=>{
      this.cart.UserId = result.id;
    });
    if(this.localListClothes != null) {
      this.cart.Clothes = JSON.parse(this.localListClothes);
    }
    console.log(this.cart)
    this.cartService.createCart(this.cart)
      .subscribe((data)=> this.cartUpdated.emit(data));
}
```

Модель данных:

```
export class ShoppingCart{

  Id?:number;

  UserId:number;

  Clothes:any;

  TotalSum?:any;

  Date?:any;

}
```

Данные не null, когда делаю запрос.

Контроллер сервера:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetCart(ShoppingCart userCart)
    {
        var find = await _context.ShoppingCart.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.UserId == userCart.UserId);


        if (find == null)
        {
            find.UserId = userCart.UserId;
            find.Clothes = userCart.Clothes;
            find.TotalSum = userCart.TotalSum;
            find.Date = DateTime.Now;
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Ok("Cart create");
        }

        if (find != null)
        {
            find.UserId = userCart.UserId;
            find.Clothes = userCart.Clothes;
            find.TotalSum = userCart.TotalSum;
            find.Date = DateTime.Now;
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Ok("Cart changed");
        }

        return BadRequest("gg,wp");
    }
```

Модель данных:

```
  public int? Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; } 
    public string Clothes { get; set; } 
    public float? TotalSum { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date = DateTime.Now;
```

Что может вызывать эту ошибку из данного кода?

Comment: `if (find == null)
        {
            find.UserId` - тут выскочит NullReferenceException.

Comment: Да, это оказалось верно.